# SQL Transpose table - sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i have the following table

```
create table mytab (
  mID int primary key,
  pname varchar(100) not null,
  pvalue varchar(100) not null
)
```

example data looks like

```
mID     |pname  |pvalue
-----------------------
1       |AAR    |   2.3
1       |AAM    |   1.2
1       |GXX    |     5
2       |AAR    |   5.4
2       |AAM    |   3.0
3       |AAR    |   0.2
```

I want to flip the table so that i get

```
mID     | AAR   |   AAM |    GXX|
---------------------------------
1       | 2.3   |   1.2 |      5|
2       | 5.4   |   3.0 |      0|
3       | 0.2   |     0 |      0
```

Is this somehow possible and if so, is there a way to create a dynamic query because there are lots of these pname pvalue pairs

Comment: You need `PIVOT`, and possibly dynamic SQL.

Comment: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `Dynamic Pivot Query` as:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colsFinal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(pname)
                      FROM mytab
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')


select @colsFinal =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(pname)+',0) AS '+ QUOTENAME(pname)
                      FROM mytab
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
--Edited query to replace null with 0 in Final result set.
SELECT @query = 'SELECT mID, '+@colsFinal +'
FROM mytab
PIVOT
(
  MAX(pvalue)
  FOR pname IN(' + @cols + ')) AS p;'


exec sp_executesql @query
```

[Check demo here..](http://rextester.com/PQWE85096)

Comment: execute(@query) missing..

Comment: @bvr thanks .. I've added that along with Demo link..

Comment: works so far, problem is i have several lines with the same mID. I wanna have one mID per row

Comment: Well that shouldn't be the case as Pivoting is already grouping on basis of mID column.. please post the row data which is creating the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot as following format:

```
select *
From (select *
     From mytab)p
PIVOT(SUM(pvalue) FOR pname IN ([AAR],[AAM],[GXX]))pvt
```

In order to dynamic `PIVOT` use flowing reference:

[Dynamic PIVOT Sample1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592798/1407421)

[Dynamic PIVOT Sample2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24754775/1407421)

Comment: your statement has a syntax error. paren is missing, and even if i close it, it won't work

Comment: I edit my post. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table (mID INT, pname VARCHAR(10),  pvalue  FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (1,'AAR',2.3)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (1,'AAM',  1.2)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (1,'GXX',  5)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (2,'AAR',  5.4)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (2,'AAM',  0.3)
INSERT INTO @t (mID,pname,pvalue)values (3,'AAR',  0.2)
select  mid,
CASE WHEN [AAR]IS NOT NULL THEN [AAR] ELSE ISNULL([AAR],0)END [AAR], 
CASE WHEN [AAM]IS NOT NULL THEN [AAM] ELSE ISNULL([AAM],0)END [AAM], 
CASE WHEN [GXX]IS NOT NULL THEN [GXX] ELSE ISNULL([GXX],0)END [GXX]
from
(
  select mID, pvalue,pname
  from @t
) d
pivot
(
  max(pvalue)
  for pname in ( [AAR], [AAM], [GXX])
) piv;
```